# Can I get a label to echo an option that has been selected in a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, combobox

Let me first point out I am a college student, a complete novice to any code! I am looking to learn new things not be shot down at the first hurdle.

My question, I have a ComboBox in a form I have called "orderform" All of my options from the menu can be selected from a series of ComboBoxes. I would like the selected option from the comboBox to be echoed into a Label which is located in a separate form called "Order_Summary". Can this be done? If so how would I go about trying to complete this task?

Many Thanks For your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be. While calling or opening other form just pass the selected text of the combobox to the forms constructor like below

```
Order_Summary os = new Order_Summary(this.combobox1.Text);
os.Show();
```

Then in `Order_Summary` form get the data and display in label like

```
    public Order_Summary(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.label1.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks brilliant help much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a reference to your other form (`Order_Summary`).
2. In the second form create a public property that returns the `Label`, or create a public method that sets the Label's text with a given value.
3. In the main form handle the `SelectedChanged` event of the `ComboBox` and use [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the item which is selected and use it to set label's text in your other form.

Comment: Hi @Selman22, Thanks for your help. Can you show me how this would look as im having some trouble implimenting what your implying.